# Hide url path from user

Tags: php

For security purpose I don't want that my users can read a url to access to a picture for example.

Actually I have

```
https://files.domain.com/TERFD/TES/photos/20150729-0961577ba8bc6c31e7339acf0c53969a170609038345c3a0602d646a48067c10-ANnKb.jpeg?uid=3&token=360d641dc692041cbea673a
```

But I prefer that the user can read the picture's path or the token

So that, I wrote the following functions :

```
public function encrypt($data) {

    $key = "df456gfd";
    $data = serialize($data);
    $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_DES,"",MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,"");
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
    mcrypt_generic_init($td,$key,$iv);
    $data = base64_encode(mcrypt_generic($td, '!'.$data));
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
    return $data;

}

public function decrypt($data) {

    $key = "df456gfd";
    $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_DES,"",MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,"");
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
    mcrypt_generic_init($td,$key,$iv);
    $data = mdecrypt_generic($td, base64_decode($data));
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);

    if (substr($data,0,1) != '!')
        return false;

    $data = substr($data,1,strlen($data)-1);
    return unserialize($data);

}
```

My URL is now:

```
https://files.domain.com/NcGDHiMnmM3fYW2W03ulyJdlCp6FaXCYDlxzWe74zH63+YpfUSPuKnxWIG1C1WNNjw/jU7coduYchvf44Lh4yiVdcL7uyx4vA4oOj14keiohQ9geIYVxsa4n07E0TXbstSETbhqGejE03Ai5hGcJEa7U/aA7z1fRkQEAxepH9j6yu+tQZESp3dXg7JUvVffI9lbpPtbGLj8=
```

I can decrypt it from files.domain.com and return the requested file.

Is it a good practice ?

Thx

Comment: You can add md5 function to make it shorter. But honestly, you made it too complicated.

Comment: Why don't you want you users to see it? The encrypting and decrypting will slow down your application.

Comment: @Randomius With md5 I can't decrypt the string (files server side)

Comment: @Daan Marketing purpose... and some url can have customer's informations

Comment: I'm pretty sure that MD5's algo always produces the same hash for a given input, so you could probably store the "real" value in a seperate area, and compare it to the hashed version afterwards.

Comment: @icecub Yes, If he wants to save a picture he can, it's just to hide the files server structure and the token.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the token will change each day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually just slowing down your application with this practice. Honestly, you're making it too complex. Why not use something like `base64_encode()` and `base64_decode()`. These functions are actually `faster` than your decryption and encryption functions.